# Usage of Jooq DSLContext in spring boot

Tags: spring, jooq

What is the proper way to use DslContext. Does having bean autoconfiguration, or calling DSL.using() method directly before execution; Do they vary in performance ?

```
@Autowired DataSource dataSource;

@PostConstruct
@Bean(name = "ExecutorDslContext")
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public DSLContext executorDslContext() {
  return DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.MEMSQL);
}
```

Should the Scope be Prototype or Singleton ?

What's the impact of using above mentioned bean for execution vs

```
Result<Record> result = DSL.using(...).select().from(TABLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq` and inject `DslContext`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.sql.jooq

Answer (score 2):

Regarding:

> calling DSL.using() method directly before execution; Do they vary in performance ?

Calling `DSL.using()` will create a new [`DefaultConfiguration`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultConfiguration.html) every time. This isn't a big overhead per se, but you won't profit from reflection caching and some other caches that can be shared among sessions that re-use the same configuration instance. In general, there's no need to create a new `Configuration` instance for every single query, so ideally just inject the shared and pre-configured `DSLContext` [as suggested by Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820029/521799)

Additional information can be found in the manual's sections

- [Performance considerations](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/performance-considerations/)
- [Thread safetey](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/thread-safety/)

Comment: I have use case of changing the Table name at runtime, so ill be creating the Settings object for it. So ill end having to use DSL.using() method. Is there a way, if i can update Settings object of DslContext bean ?

Comment: The `Settings` object contains mapping information, which will also be translated to a more appropriate format, and then cached. I suggest you create a singleton instance of a `Configuration` containing your settings, not calling `DSL.using()` every time before you run a query.